# How to change an svg image after onClick()?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have a div tab that contains some text and an svg icon like so[image]

Once I click that tab then it expands like so

[image]

Once expanded I want the svg icon to change to something else. So far my code isn't throwing me any errors but also isn't working as expected either. I currently have a function that should change the icon to icon-cancel.svg after the element is clicked nothing changes. Here is what I have.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>

    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
      }
      #side-chat {
        position: absolute;
        right: 100%;
        bottom:50%;
        z-index:9999999999999 !important;
        width: 150px;
        margin-right: -59px;
        transform: rotate(-90deg);
        display:flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        color: #ffffff;
        border-radius: 10px;
        background: rgba(30, 175, 230, 0.5);
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 15px;
        font-size: 25px;
        line-height: 20px;
        text-align: center;    
      }
      #olark-box-wrapper {
        position: absolute;
        z-index:99999999999999 !important;
        top: 400px;
        right: -300px;

        -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
        -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
        -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
        transition-duration: 0.3s;
      }
      #olark-box-wrapper.chatbox-open {
        right: 0
      }
      #olark-box-wrapper.chatbox-closed {
       right: -300px;
      }
      #habla_window_div {
        margin: 0 !important;
      }
      #side-chat img{
        margin-right: 10px;
        
      }
      #side-chat:hover,
      #side-chat:active {
       background: #22a7e5;
}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
<div id="olark-box-wrapper">

  <!-- Olark chat tab -->
    <a id="side-chat" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="changeClass(); changeImage();">
      <img src="icon-chat.svg">
         Chat
    </a>

  <!-- Empty Olark chat box container -->
  <div id="olark-box-container"></div>

</div>

<!-- begin olark code -->
<script type="text/javascript" async> ;(function(o,l,a,r,k,y){if(o.olark)return; r="script";y=l.createElement(r);r=l.getElementsByTagName(r)[0]; y.async=1;y.src="//"+a;r.parentNode.insertBefore(y,r); y=o.olark=function(){k.s.push(arguments);k.t.push(+new Date)}; y.extend=function(i,j){y("extend",i,j)}; y.identify=function(i){y("identify",k.i=i)}; y.configure=function(i,j){y("configure",i,j);k.c[i]=j}; k=y._={s:[],t:[+new Date],c:{},l:a}; })(window,document,"static.olark.com/jsclient/loader.js");
  /* custom configuration goes here (www.olark.com/documentation) */
  //olark.configure('system.hb_detached', true);
  olark.configure('box.inline', true);
  olark.identify('xxxx-xxx-xx-xxxx');</script>
  <!-- end olark code -->
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    // Javacript function to toggle the class of the chat box wrapper
    function changeClass()
    {
      // Get the HTML object containing the Olark chat box
      var olark_wrapper = document.getElementById("olark-box-wrapper");
      // If the chat box is already open, close id
      if ( olark_wrapper.className.match(/(?:^|\s)chatbox-open(?!\S)/) ) {
        olark_wrapper.className = "chatbox-closed";
       
      }
      // Otherwise add open the Olark chat box
      else {        
        olark_wrapper.className = "chatbox-open";
        
      }
        
    }


  function changeImage(){
document.getElementById('side-chat').src = "icon-cancel.svg";
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You want `getElementById` here:  `document.getElementId('side-chat').src = "icon-cancel.svg";`

Comment: looks like an old code. have you tried classList.toggle()  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList (to avoid regex) , event.listener https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener then setAttribute  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute to swap your svg uri ?

Comment: @RobMoll that was a typo in my question, that's in my original code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "side-chat" element is the `<a>` tag which does not have a src.
Try changing getElementById to querySelector to get the image inside instead.

```
 function changeImage(){
     document.querySelector('#side-chat img').src = "icon-cancel.svg";
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

after opening the code inside the svg file

path

Copy everything between the svg codes. Then add an onclick event. I think your problem will be solved if you add a click event like svg.innerHTML = `what you copied` when clicked. Since svg files consist of vectors, the path codes in them determine the icon. When it changes, the icon will also change. I hope I could help.

```js
var svg = document.querySelector('.svg');
        svg.addEventListener('click',()=>{
            svg.innerHTML=`
           <path d="M242.72 256l100.07-100.07c12.28-12.28 12.28-32.19 0-44.48l-22.24-22.24c-12.28-12.28-32.19-12.28-44.48 0L176 189.28 75.93 89.21c-12.28-12.28-32.19-12.28-44.48 0L9.21 111.45c-12.28 12.28-12.28 32.19 0 44.48L109.28 256 9.21 356.07c-12.28 12.28-12.28 32.19 0 44.48l22.24 22.24c12.28 12.28 32.2 12.28 44.48 0L176 322.72l100.07 100.07c12.28 12.28 32.2 12.28 44.48 0l22.24-22.24c12.28-12.28 12.28-32.19 0-44.48L242.72 256z"></path>
            `
        })
```

```css
  .svg
        {
            width: 30px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
```

```html
 <h2>Click svg</h2>
    <svg aria-hidden="true" class="svg" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="bars" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512"><path d="M16 132h416c8.837 0 16-7.163 16-16V76c0-8.837-7.163-16-16-16H16C7.163 60 0 67.163 0 76v40c0 8.837 7.163 16 16 16zm0 160h416c8.837 0 16-7.163 16-16v-40c0-8.837-7.163-16-16-16H16c-8.837 0-16 7.163-16 16v40c0 8.837 7.163 16 16 16zm0 160h416c8.837 0 16-7.163 16-16v-40c0-8.837-7.163-16-16-16H16c-8.837 0-16 7.163-16 16v40c0 8.837 7.163 16 16 16z"></path></svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your function you are changing the src of an `<a>` tag. But you want to change it from the `<img>` tag. So your selector is wrong.

```
document.getElementById('side-chat') - outputs the <a> tag
```

Just add an id to the `<img>` tag and select this id.
Then you can
document.getElementById('imgId').src = "other img path"
Inside  your changeImg() function.